# Making a value/ordinary text, clickable and changeable

Tags: jquery, html

This .js code below gives out the view that is visible on the picture attached.
As you can probably make out of the code, depending on the value of the array (1 or 0 )
The shown value is "yes" or "no".

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this "yes" or "no" value clickable in a sense that it changes from Yes to No.

```
if(y.email.contact_email == 1){
    contact = "<td class='value'><span style='color: green'>Yes</span></td>";
}

else
{
    contact = "<td class='value'><span style='color: red'>No</span></td>";
}

content += "<tr class='odd'><td class='key'>Contact </br> e-mail</td><td class='value'>"+contact+"</td></tr>";

if(y.email.login_email == 1){
    login = "<td class='value'><span style='color: green'>Yes</span></td>";
}

else
{
    login = "<td class='value'><span style='color: red'>No</span></td>";
}

content += "<tr class='even'><td class='key'>Users login </br> e-mail</td><td class='value'>"+login+"</td></tr>";
```

[image: image of output]

Comment: I have an idea how to do this with checkboxes...                          
 checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="crm" id="crm" checked="checked" onChange="changeNotificationStatus();"/>';
                    }else{
                        checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="crm" id="crm" onChange="changeNotificationStatus();"/>';
                    }

Comment: I don't know if it was intentional, but you end up with double `<td class='value'>` around each of the "Yes" or "No" strings.

Comment: Yeah..I did that on purpose. :-) thx for noticing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('td.value span').click(function() {
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes' );
});
```

Comment: +1 - You beat me to it. You might add that the code is jQuery -- just to be thorough. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! SO gives me hope in humanity :-D

Comment: @Herbert - Its that I take jQuery for granted so much that i sometimes forget its an external tool that needs to be included etc. :)

Comment: @techfoobar So do I. In fact, failing to include it has been a source of frustration for me from time to time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using divs you could try :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(linkid) {
        var toggleLink = document.getElementById(linkid);
        if (toggleLink.innerHTML == 'No') {
            toggleLink.innerHTML = 'Yes';
        }
        else {
            toggleLink.innerHTML = 'No';
        }
    }
</script>

<a id="yesNo" onclick="toggle(this.id);" href="#">Yes</a>
```

If you need to store these values back to another script or db then simply create a hidden form field and update the value of the hidden field within the toggle function above (e.g. document.getElementById( 'hiddenField' ).value = "0" )

Dave